# How can I redirect a subdirectory to the root directory in an apache webserver?

Tags: apache, silverstripe

My website can be accessed from `mydomain.com/new_site/test/public/<page>` or `mydomain.com/<page>`, but I want the first form redirect to the second form. In essence, how do i redirect all pages of a site of the first form to a url of the second form?

Currently, this is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new_site/test/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new_site/test/public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ new_site/test/public/index.php [L]
```

The purpose of the htaccess is to allow all links to be accessed through a url of the second form. The issue is, this does not create a redirection from the first form to the second form.

Comment: Are you saying that your current `.htaccess` works, content is served from the correct URLs, but the browser does not redirect?  If yes, it is simply a matter of adding `R=301` to the flags at the end of your `RewriteRule`.  There are **many** examples of this here on SO.

Comment: A word of warning - I'm not familiar with Silverstripe, but if its public files are in `public/`, it probably means that should be your docroot, as that prevents access to sensitive files.  If you can browse the site at `/new_site/test/public/`, it probably means that files in `/new_site/test/` are also exposed to the world - and that is very likely to include sensitive files, eg `.env`, config files with credentials etc.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I tried adding that to the [L] at the end of the last line, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That's something I was wondering about. Is it enough to just restrict access to anything besides the public subdirectory?

Comment: `R` *is* how you do an external redirect - external meaning the browser actually makes a new request and the URL in the location bar changes.  [Check the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), or see other examples here on SO.  You have 2 `RewriteRule`s, you likely need to add it to both.  Regarding security - how would you `restrict access`, completely and safely?  IMO the *only* option is to set your docroot to `public/` - anything else is a hack and asking for trouble.